# How to use Scandinavian characters in LaTeX math mode?

Tags: math-mode, unicode, accents, scandinavian-letters

Here's a MWE/MNWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{icomma}
\begin{document}
Regular text with Scandinavian characters (å, ä, ö, ø, æ) works fine. 
Using Å as unit (ångström) fails in math mode: $ 3,0\,\mathrm{Å} $ -- 
there isn't even a regular ''add a circle above'' diacritic macro afaik 
-- and also using å as a variable fails for example in $ (å-1)^2 $ and 
$ \dfrac{\mathrm{d}å(t)}{\mathrm{d}t} $ , but I \emph{really} need it 
to work. \end{document}
```

[image: how Scandinavian characters fail to render]

Without the T1 option, I get the "Please use \mathaccent" error. With these settings, it compiles and renders although I do get a mention of ''Command \r invalid in math mode'' in the log. In the result, the characters simply aren't drawn.

I am **not** looking for specific macros to draw diacritics. I am **not** meant to type all those characters in `\text` mode as they are not text in this case but actual variables which can therefore still be differentiated and whatnot. `\mathit` does not work (still no render) nor is it acceptable.

Is this a font-specific problem and the corresponding characters just don't exist in the font's math version? If that is the case, which fonts include math versions of the Scandics? I've tried at least `kpfonts` and `fourier`.

Is the only way out to move on from LaTeX? (This would be fine if it was just for me but my coworkers have to be able to work with these files as well.)

Comment: Yes, it's font-specific. Try `\usepackage{lmodern}`. That works.

Comment: Off-topic but ''...'' will give bad results, as you can see, you need to be using ``...''

Comment: the standard math fonts do not have these characters but you can use `\mathring{a}` `\ddot{a}`  ø is tricker I suppose either `\text{ø}` to get it from the text fonts or   `\empty`

Comment: @TeXnician That seems to work for now, but I'd consider that as suboptimal as the package seems to be unmaintained. Also, the math fonts for å etc. aren't slanted; they seem to be simply copied over from the text mode characters. This is convenient for now but apparently we're still missing proper math versions of those characters.

Any way I can just use `lmodern` for math but leave my text font intact?

Comment: It's not unmaintained, but a finished font that doesn't need updates so often. It was introduced as a replacement for the default Computer Modern. But maybe someone will add some "proper" math answer.

Comment: @Au101 [Swedish typographic practice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark#Finnish_and_Swedish) uses the “closing style” both before and after.

Comment: @svenper Ah well that is indeed very interesting. Thanks! I didn't know that! Having said that, the MWE is in English

Comment: @Au101 It's in English for your sake. I'll be mostly typing in Finnish. :)

Answer (score 9):

There *is* a regular command for a circle above a letter: `\mathring`.

For the angstrom unit, use `siunitx`, which avoids the need for `icomma`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}

\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}

\begin{document}

Regular text with Scandinavian characters (å, ä, ö, ø, æ) works fine. 
Using Å as unit (ångström) fails in math mode: $\SI{3,0}{\angstrom}$ -- 
there isn't even a regular ``add a circle above'' diacritic macro afaik 
-- and also using å as a variable fails for example in $ (\mathring{a}-1)^2 $ and 
$ \dfrac{\diff\mathring{a}(t)}{\diff t}$, but I \emph{really} need it 
to work.

\end{document}
```

[image]

You *may* input `å` in math mode for `\mathring{a}`, but I can't recommend it; you don't type `ü` for the second derivative, do you?

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}

\newcommand{\diff}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}}
\newunicodechar{å}{\ifmmode\mathring{a}\else\r{a}\fi}

\begin{document}

Regular text with Scandinavian characters (å, ä, ö, ø, æ) works fine. 
Using Å as unit (ångström) fails in math mode: $\SI{3,0}{\angstrom}$ -- 
there isn't even a regular ``add a circle above'' diacritic macro afaik 
-- and also using å as a variable fails for example in $ (å-1)^2 $ and 
$ \dfrac{\diff å(t)}{\diff t}$, but I \emph{really} need it 
to work.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the `mathring`hint; although I doubt I'll ever use it (but you never know). I'm (mostly for didactic reasons) interested in using ≈*anything* as a variable, so my goal is simply to be able to replace English latin alphabet characters with a more wider set as variables, regardless of accents. The ring is not important, the character as a whole is, and I'm typing it directly from the keyboard. (So I completely agree with the "you don't type `ü`" thing. Didn't even cross my mind. :P)

Comment: I've yet to be convinced to use `siunitx` as its syntax is more cumbersome than simply typing the number myself and defining my own unit macro. After defining
    `\newcommand{\unit}[1]{\ensuremath{\,\mathrm{#1}}}`
I can simply type `$3,0\unit{Å}$` which is alot briefer than `$\SI{3,0}{\angstrom}$`. I don't get the benefits. I would certainly appreciate if someone could elaborate on this, although this is off-topic. 

I also regularly have the differential operator defined already.

Comment: @JoonasD6 Suppose your document is to be submitted to a journal which *requires* a decimal dot, rather than a comma…

Comment: Alright, future-proofing. :) What I'm usually working on has nothing that would be localised elsewhere, but suppose I could just in case at least load the package for a potential document where it would be uncertain what the specific typographic standards will be.

Thank you.

Comment: Although one more question: can you imagine there being a problem with `siunitx` when sometimes only using numbers and sometimes only using units in mathematical expressions? It is often necessary for me to only consider units when I teach people how to use them – dimensional analysis in general.

Comment: @JoonasD6 The package provides `\num` for numbers alone and `\si` for units alone.

Comment: `\textit{å}` seems to work ok in math mode.

Comment: @Oni The key word is indeed “seems”. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The math fonts do not have these characters but you can set things up to automatically use italic in mathm mode:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{icomma}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{C5}{\relax\ifmmode\textit{\AA}\else\AA\fi}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{E5}{\relax\ifmmode\textit{\aa}\else\aa\fi}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{E6}{\relax\ifmmode\textit{\ae}\else\ae\fi}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{C4}{\relax\ifmmode\textit{\"{a}}\else\"{a}\fi}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{D8}{\relax\ifmmode\textit{\o}\else\o\fi}

\begin{document}
Regular text with Scandinavian characters (å, ä, ö, ø, æ) works fine. 
Using Å as unit (ångström) fails in math mode: $ 3,0\,\mathrm{Å} $ -- 
there isn't even a regular ''add a circle above'' diacritic macro afaik 
-- and also using å as a variable fails for example in $ (å-1)^2 $ and 
$ \dfrac{\mathrm{d}å(t)}{\mathrm{d}t} $ , but I \emph{really} need it 
to work. \end{document}
```

Comment: Was that definition supposed to override `\mathrm`? Because it did and now the unit `Å` is slanted although it should be upright.

Comment: @JoonasD6 if you always want Å  to be upright just replace `\textit` by `\texrm` in its definition, but yes these end up working like greek letters in math where `\mathrm{\alpha}` doesn't make alpha upright and `\mathit{\Gamma}` doesn't make Gamma slanted. To do more really requires better font support which is beyond the scope of an answer here, sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can use any text-mode command in math mode by wrapping it in `\textnormal`.  For example:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\mathAring{\textnormal{\itshape Å}}
```

If you load `fontspec`, it will also set your `\mathrm` font to the default text font and `\mathit` to its italic shape, so `\mathit{Å}` should just work.